# How you can create your 12 columnar grid on the similarity of the bootstrap

Tags: html, css

How you can create your 12 columnar grid on the similarity of the bootstrap.How to make payments?

Comment: payments? And why do you need to recreate bootstrap? If you would like to know how they do it your could just read their css.

Comment: What do you mean with payments? Easy way is using html´s tag <table>. But this tag is obsolote. Proper way is playing with <div> and its attributes: border, height, width, position,... and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.col-12{width:100%}
.col-11{width:91.66666667%}
.col-10{width:83.33333333%}
.col-9{width:75%}
.col-8{width:66.66666667%}
.col-7{width:58.33333333%}
.col-6{width:50%}
.col-5{width:41.66666667%}
.col-4{width:33.33333333%}
.col-3{width:25%}
.col-2{width:16.66666667%}
.col-1{width:8.33333333%}
```

this will work.

Comment: @RohitChopraAnd  how do you calculated?the question was how exactly this is done

Comment: Check the css´s file.

Comment: i have divided the screen into 12 columns. and calculated the width of each column like width for 1 column is 1/12 and converted into percentage. so that if the screen is small it can adjust accordingly.

Comment: @RohitChopra I understand ,thank you